# Opening Control Port On Tor

Tags: torsocks

It seems that when I enable the control port on port 9051, the IP would be 127.0.0.1:9051.  When I visit the website, it says that it is a socks proxy, not an HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're enabling the control port on port 9051, and trying to connect in your browser to `127.0.0.1:9051`? Tor's control port doesn't work like this. You need to communicate with the control port using Tor's [control protocol](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt). It's easiest to use software that is designed to communicate with tor's control port like [nyx](https://nyx.torproject.org/), or if you know Python then a library like [stem](https://stem.torproject.org/).